# Upgrade process for Facebook deep linking in iOS and Android app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, deep-linking

I updated iOS and Android apps to use deep linking from Facebook posts as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/

Everything works fine for the new app. My problem is that many people will have the older version of the app that does not handle deep linking. Since I was using Facebook SDK login, the url schemes, etc were already set up.

The only solution I can think of is to wait for a month to give most people the opportunity to upgrade then enable deep linking in the app settings. This is far from ideal.

Has anyone else faced this problem and found a better solution?

Comment: How did you manage to make deep linking work? What is the link you share? "myappurl://" ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested with old versions of your app, and does it crash?

For iOS, if you don't already have url handling logic setup (in your openURL method in the AppDelegate), it *should* just open your app, and do nothing else.

On Android, if your deeplink handling class is a new class (and does not exist in your old app), then the FB app won't deeplink if it cannot find that class on the device.

Comment: On both ios and android old app, it just launches the app and nothing else. This is a poor user experience since they are expecting to see the linked content. The problem is the old apps were set up for the sdk login, so all the url schems, key hashes, class names, etc are all set up, so once I check deep linking in the settings, it deep links for all versions of the app.

Comment: For iOS, there's no good solution I can think of off the top of my head. For Android, you can just use a new classname for deep linking (login doesn't use the classname at all), so it shouldn't interfere with your existing app.

Comment: I can't use a new classname in Android because it's in the app settings for the SDK login. I guess there is no good solutions. Thanks though.

Comment: SDK login DOES NOT use your classname. It's only used for deep linking. So if you didn't implement deep links previously, you can change the classname at will.

Comment: The facebook instructions said to put in the package and classname when setting up the app for the sdk, so that's what I did. Not sure what the consequences of changing it at this point would be.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/